# Node.js npm is not running the file i want to instead it is running another file in the same folder

Tags: node.js

I have a file named serverReg.js in a folder. When i execute this file by typing nodemon serverReg.js another file named register.js starts running instead of that file.
I am a beginner and don't know much.

Output saying connect is written in the code of register.js file

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nodemon checks for fields in [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X0Hn.png), please check this